# Update a variable group snapshot for an Azure DevOps release

Tags: variables, azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps release pipeline that references several variable groups, with each stage in the release being linked to a different group.

When I first deploy to a stage, one of the values required for that variable group cannot be known (a key for a function on a Function App). However, it's required for some post deployment checks that need to be completed.

It's not ideal, but I thought I'd be able to do the deployment, have it fail, update the variable group and then try again. This is based on the following statement when you edit a release -

> You can edit approvals, tasks, and variables

However, it seems that if you edit a variable group there is no way to pull the updated values in to the release. This means that the only way I can get my deployment out is to create a second release.

I'm really hoping that I'm missing something, because other tools (e.g. Octopus) offer this functionality out of the box. Is it possible to update a variable group snapshot for a release?

Answer (score 5):

Variable group snapshot cannot be modified in the deployed release currently. Azure devops release doesnot support this feature yet.

However, variables defined under **Variables** tab can be modified in previously deployed release.

So as workaround, you can define a variable which has the same name under **Variables** to override the variable defined in the variable group. (For example, i have a variable `Name` in variable group, then i defined a new variable under Variables also named `Name`)

See below:

1, Edit your release and choose `Edit release`
[image]

2, Click Variables tab --> Add a new variable(eg. `Name`) which has the same name with the variable in the variable group--> Save

[image]

3,After saving the changes. Go to **Pipeline** tab--> to **Redeploy** your release. Then the updated values will be pulled in to the release

[image]

You can click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to submit a user voice(Click suggest a feature and choose Azure Devops)to Microsoft Development team. Hope they will consider adding this feature in the feature sprint

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll give it a try, but I really hope that this feature is added to Azure DevOps - it seems that all do these days is try to find workarounds so that I can implement basic functionality that Azure DevOps can't do out of the box.

Comment: You can click here to [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click suggest a feature and choose Azure Devops)to Microsoft Development team. Hope they will consider adding this feature in the feature sprint.

Comment: @DavidGard If you are using yaml pipeline. You can try setting [output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) using scripts. And pass the variables between stages. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages)

Comment: Also choose the correct scope when you add the variable. Using scope Release will not replace the value if the variable group si scoped to a given stage.