# Update variable group variables within release

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I've got an variable group linked to my release in Azure DevOps. I'm using ARM templates to deploy to create the Azure infrastructure and I'm reading the output of the ARM deployment into variables in the the variable group that is linked with the release.  To do this I'm using VSTeam (https://github.com/MethodsAndPractices/vsteam) and this works fine.
My issue is that I'm using the variables later in the release (in another stage) and it seems they don't get updated when updated with the REST API.  Was wondering if it was possible to refresh the variable group so it would get the latest values or if there where some other way.

How I update the variable group variables:

```
# Update variable group
$UpdateVariableGroup = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $VariableGroup -Depth 100 -Compress
Write-Host -Object "Updating variable group"
$Result = Update-VSTeamVariableGroup -Body $UpdateVariableGroup -ProjectName "$(System.TeamProject)" -Id $VariableGroup.id
```

Regards,
Oskar

Comment: Very similar question with an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260744/update-a-variable-group-snapshot-for-an-azure-devops-release

From my experience, the release creates a 'snapshot' of the variable groups. The only way to edit the variable group values was to edit the release itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems to cover my issue yes.

Comment: The only issue I can see with that solution though is that the release variable is overriding the variable group variable as it has the same name.  I would like the release to use the variable group variable as that is persisted across different releases.  I would then only want to use the release variable if I need to update the value of the variable group variable.  Going to give it a try.

Comment: And that is exactly what happens. I can't choose if I want to use the variable group variable or the release variable and the release fails unless the variable is set each release.

Comment: ​Guess I could read the values from the variable group using the API at the start of each stage.

Answer (score 0):

> Update variable group variables within release

Just as you know, The variable group is preloaded at the beginning of the pipeline, and the variable group will not be refreshed in the subsequent release process.

If your pipeline is YAML mode, we could share variables across stages instead of replacing the values in the variable group：

```
stageDependencies.{stageName}.{jobName}.outputs['{stepName}.{variableName}']
```

You could check [this document](https://gaunacode.com/passing-variables-between-jobs-for-azure-devops-pipelines) for some more details.

If your pipeline is classic mode, we have to use release variable override the variable group variable in each release. If you do not want to set those variables in each release, you could try to define some backup variables in the release variable, then use REST API to update the name and value of those variables.